# How to handle Japanese characters?

Tags: python, mutagen

I have an input in Japanese language from other source which is out of my control.

But I get this error:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 15-41: character maps to undefined`

Code:

```
import mutagen

def addTag(fpath, title, albumName):
    audio = mutagen.File(fpath, easy=True)
    audio.add_tags()
    audio['title'] = title
    audio['album'] = albumName
    audio.save(fpath)

# The Code below this comment is out of my control but this is how it is implemented
file = "1.mp3"
title = "We Must Go TV"
album = "アニメ「風が強く吹いている」オリジナルサウンドトラック"
addTag(file, title, album)
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error message (stacktrace)?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10669875) And when you get an Exception in Python, it always includes a stacktrace (including the line number where the error occurs). This is important information. Please copy-paste it into your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

It says how to process and include non-ASCII text in your Python code. Essentially, you use unicode literals to represent a single character. This will print one character:

```
ru = u'\u30EB'
```

You could also try to force the string to be a `unicode` object in python 2:

```
album = u"\uアニメ「風が強く吹いている」オリジナルサウンドトラック"
```

By default, all strings are already unicode.

Also check out this informative video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oEbNWXhS_mk

Comment: This assignment `album = ur"アニメ「風が強く吹いている」オリジナルサウンドトラック"` gives a syntax error.  The prefix `ur` is invalid: you can't combine `u` and `r` in Python 3. The `u` is in any case redundant. That was Python 2 syntax for a Unicode literal. It was only retained in Python 3 to make porting code easier.  Python 3 does not have "unicode objects". In Python 3 they are strings.

Answer (score -1):

there are 2 solutions

[image]
1- when you look at end of error message you will see the encoding library have the issue in my case it was cp1252 I could insert the value by encode string first to utf-8 then decode the string to the library have the issue and used ignore errors so data will inserted but the unknown characters will replaced with not needed characters eg: ð¥ð¢ð ð¡ð­ ð“ð, but this not best way but good for inserting the data without errors

```
newCatalogue.product_description = newCatalogue.product_description.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252', 'ignore')
```

second and this what I used I added charset in connection url and data inserted normal

```
mysql://user:pass@localhost/dbname?charset=utf8mb4
```